# How to get href from a class containing a specific text using CSS selector (Scrapy)

Tags: python, css, regex, web-scraping, scrapy

I am working with the following web site: https://inmuebles.mercadolibre.com.mx/venta/, and I am trying to get the link from "ver_todos" button from "Inmueble" section (in red). However, the "Tour virtual" and "Publicados hoy" sections (in blue) may or may not appear when visiting the site.

[image]

As shown in the image below, the classes `ui-search-filter-dl` contain the specific sections from the menu from above image; while `ui-search-filter-container` classes contain the sub-sections displayed by the site (e.g. Casas, Departamento & Terrenos for Inmueble). With the intention of obtaining the link from "ver todos" button from "Inmueble" section, I was using this line of code:

```
ver_todos = response.css('div.ui-search-filter-dl')[2].css('a.ui-search-modal__link').attrib['href']
```

But since "Tour virtual" and "Publicados hoy" are not always in the page, I cannot be sure that `ui-search-filter-dl` at index 2 is always the index corresponding to "ver todos" button.

[image]

I was trying to get the link from "ver todos" by using this line of code:

```
response.css(''':contains("Inmueble") ~ .ui-search-filter-dt-title
                            .ui-search-modal__link::attr(href)''').extract()
```

Basically, I was trying to get the href from a `ui-search-filter-dt-title` class that contains the title "Inmueble". Unfortunately, the output is an empty list. I would like to find the link from "ver todos" by using css and regex but I'm having trouble with it. How may I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think xpath is easier to select the target elements in most cases:

### Code:

```py
xpath = "//div[contains(text(), 'Inmueble')]/following-sibling::ul//a[contains(@class,'ui-search-modal__link')]/@href"
url = response.xpath(xpath).extract()[0]
```

Actually, I didn't create a scrapy project to check your code. Alternatively, I implemented the following code:

```py
from lxml import html
import requests

res = requests.get( "https://inmuebles.mercadolibre.com.mx/venta/")

dom = html.fromstring(res.text)

xpath = "//div[contains(text(), 'Inmueble')]/following-sibling::ul//a[contains(@class,'ui-search-modal__link')]/@href"
url = dom.xpath(xpath)[0]

assert url == 'https://inmuebles.mercadolibre.com.mx/venta/_FiltersAvailableSidebar?filter=PROPERTY_TYPE'
```

Since the xpath should be the same among scrapy and lxml, of course, I hope the code shown in the beginning will also work fine in your scrapy project.

Comment: I'll update my answer if I come up with another approach using css and regex that you referred to in your question post.

Comment: It does what I wanted although I would have preferred to use css. However, it works just fine!!!

Answer (score 0):

An easy way you could do it is by getting all the link `<a>` and then checking if any of their text matches `ver todos`.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://inmuebles.mercadolibre.com.mx/venta/"

def main():
  res = requests.get(link)
  if res.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
    links = [a["href"] for a in soup.select("a") if a.text.strip().lower() == "ver todos"]
    print(links)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```